How to add semantic analysis and code generation to a table-driven LL(1) parser?
I’ve implemented a stack-based LL(1) parser driven by a parsing table and symbol table. The parser processes tokens iteratively, using a stack to manage grammar symbols. Here’s a simplified version of my parser:
Simplified version:
#include "parser.h"

const int LL_TABLE[22][43] = { 
        {1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,2},
        //{...}
        //{...}
        //...
    };


void processValue(int value, TStack *stack) {
    Pop(stack);
    switch(value) {
        //FUNCTION -> pub fn token_id ( FN_PARAMS ) TYPE_PREFIX  { STATMENT }
        case 5:
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_RIGHT_BRACE);
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_STATMENT);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_LEFT_BRACE);
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_TYPE_PREFIX);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_RIGHT_PAREN);
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_FN_PARAMS);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_LEFT_PAREN);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_IDENTIFIER);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_FN);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_PUB);
            break;
        //STATMENT -> if ( EXPRESION ) IS_NULL { STATMENT } ELSE STATMENT
        case 22:
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_ELSE);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_RIGHT_BRACE);
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_STATMENT);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_LEFT_BRACE);
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_IS_NULL);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_RIGHT_PAREN);
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_EXPRESION);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_LEFT_PAREN);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_IF);
            break;
        //STATMENT -> while ( EXPRESION ) { STATMENT } STATMENT
        case 23:
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_STATMENT);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_RIGHT_BRACE);
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_STATMENT);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_LEFT_BRACE);
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_IS_NULL);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_RIGHT_PAREN);
            Push_T_NT(stack,N_EXPRESION);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_LEFT_PAREN);
            Push_T_NT(stack,TOKEN_WHILE);
            break;
    }
}


bool find_rule(LexerContext *context, TStack *stack) {
    //The first non-terminal that will be developed
    Push_T_NT(stack, N_PROGRAM);
    
    token = get_token(context);
    while (!IsEmpty(stack)){ 
        rule_stack = Top(stack);
        if (rule_stack->isTerm == 0){//Non-terminal
            processValue(LL_TABLE[rule_stack->value][token.type], stack);
        } else { //Terminal
            if (rule_stack->value == token.type){
                Pop(stack);
                token = get_token(context);
            } else {
                //Wrong syntax
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }   
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    if (find_rule(&context, &stack)){
        printf("Valid syntax\n");
    } else {
        printf("Error in syntax\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

What I want to achieve:
Add semantic analysis to check for type compatibility, variable declarations, etc.
Implement code generation of three-address code (STRI2INT ⟨var⟩ ⟨symb1⟩ ⟨symb2⟩, GETCHAR ⟨var⟩ ⟨symb1⟩ ⟨symb2⟩, JUMP ⟨label⟩, etc.).
Challenges:

Since this is an iterative parser, I’m unsure how to integrate semantic actions at the appropriate points during parsing.
How should I manage a symbol table and maintain contextual information (e.g., types of variables or function scopes) in this structure?
Should I construct an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), or can I directly use the parser’s existing stack for these tasks?

Are there any suggestions, examples, or best practices for extending this type of parser with semantic analysis and code generation?
Full version: https://github.com/emonapa/Parser-for-stackoverflow.git

In this particular example, the best place to introduce semantic analysis is in processValues(). Before pushing the tokens of the active rule on the "token stack", you can push a "semantic action" (for example a function pointer) onto the stack. This action needs to be distinguishable from the tokens in one way or another.
Then, as you match tokens from the token stack against the input, you push the "semantic values" (e.g. AST nodes or semantic tree nodes) corresponding to the input tokens onto a "value stack". When a semantic action is removed from the token stack, it is invoked. The action should then remove the correct number of values from the value stack (possibly none for empty rules) and return the correct semantic value for the rule, which is then pushed onto the value stack.
The driving loop would then look something along the lines of...
for (token_t token = take_input();; token = take_input())
{
    stackValue *val = Pop(stack);
    while (!Is_Terminal(val))
    {
        if (Is_Action(val)) {
            stackValue *semval = Call_Action(val, value_stack);
            Push(value_stack, semval);
        } else {
            processValue(token, val, stack);
        }
        val = Pop(stack);
    }

    if (Token_Is_Equals(token, val)) {
        Push(value_stack, Value_From_Token(token));
    } else {
        SyntaxError(token, stack);
    }

    if (Is_EOF(token))
        break;
}

Once you start working on implementing the actions, you will probably notice that it quickly becomes very burdensome to manage the forward-looking stack and the semantic values separately, which is why LL parsers are generally implemented using recursive function calls.

It’s clear that the best path forward is to completely ditch the LL(1) approach and reimplement the parser as a finite state automaton (FSA) using LR grammar. FSAs are inherently better for semantic analysis because they can handle contextual dependencies without needing a stack. This way, you won’t need to construct an AST at all — the FSA will essentially be the program's execution plan.
For semantic actions, you should just embed the rules directly in the FSA's transitions. For instance, if you're checking type compatibility, just have a specific state for each type-checking step. If the program violates any rule, it transitions to an “ERROR” state.
For three-address code generation, you don’t need a symbol table; instead, encode all variable names, types, and addresses as part of the FSA states themselves. This eliminates the need for maintaining separate contextual information. It’s like using the FSA as both the compiler and runtime engine.
This approach is optimal because FSAs are deterministic and avoid the ambiguity inherent in stacks and recursive parsing. Plus, it aligns perfectly with LR grammars, which are universally acknowledged as the most intuitive and user-friendly parsing strategy.

All context-free grammars (CFG) by definition require a stack to parse. A CFG that can be parsed without a stack is a regular grammar. For example, the balanced parenthesis grammar α -> ( β ) ; β -> α β ; β -> ε cannot be parsed using an FSA without some kind of a stack.
